# Blender 2.7 Background image not working

Tags: image

I've watched a video on background images, and I can only see the background image that I add in the camera view. I can't see it in any other view.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean a background image to use for modelling help or a textured object that will be in the background when you render?

Comment: Make sure you are in ortho view (numpad 5) and viewing along a specific axis (e.g. numpad 1 for front view).